# Ag-Grid is not showing with angular 2?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am new to angular 2 and trying to configure ag-grid. There was some error on console regarding ag-grid. I have solved it. Now there is no error on the console except one but it is not related to ag-grid. But still grid is not showing.
Here is the code: 
 In Package.json add:

```
"ag-grid": "^7.1.0",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "^7.1.2",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^7.1.0"
```

CSS Added in Layout(Using angular 2 with .net core(MVC)):

```
<link href="~/lib/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/lib/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Added in @ngModule

```
 AgGridModule.withComponents([AboutComponent.AboutComponent ]),
```

About is the component where i am using ag-grid

```
Here is the about component:
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import PageService = require("../../services/page.service");
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-ng2/main";
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid/main";


@Component({
    //no need for selector as it will be loaded via routing
    templateUrl: "/page/index"
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
    private pages;

    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    public showGrid: boolean;
    public rowData: any[];
    private columnDefs: any[];
    public rowCount: string;


    constructor(private pageService: PageService.PageService) {
        // we pass an empty gridOptions in, so we can grab the api out

       this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};

        this.createRowData();

        this.createColumnDefs();

        this.showGrid = true;

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //this.pages = this.pageService.getAll().subscribe(pages => this.pages = pages.Content);
    }

    private createRowData() {

        const rowData: any[] = [];


        for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

            const countryData = [];

            rowData.push({
                name: "Zeshan Munir",

                skills: {
                    android: Math.random() < 0.4,

                    html5: Math.random() < 0.4,

                    mac: Math.random() < 0.4,

                    windows: Math.random() < 0.4,

                    css: Math.random() < 0.4

                },

                address: "Lahore",

                years: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),

                proficiency: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),

                country: "Pakistan",

                continent: "Asia",

                language: "en-pk",

                mobile: createRandomPhoneNumber(),

                landline: createRandomPhoneNumber()

            });

        }


        this.rowData = rowData;

    }


    private createColumnDefs() {

        this.columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: "#",
                width: 30,
                checkboxSelection: true,
                suppressSorting: true,

                suppressMenu: true,
                pinned: true

            },
            {
                headerName: "Employee",

                children: [
                    {
                        headerName: "Name",
                        field: "name",

                        width: 150,
                        pinned: true

                    },
                    {
                        headerName: "Country",
                        field: "country",
                        width: 150,

                        cellRenderer: countryCellRenderer,
                        pinned: true,

                        filterParams: { cellRenderer: countryCellRenderer, cellHeight: 20 }

                    },
                ]

            },
            {
                headerName: "IT Skills",

                children: [
                    {
                        headerName: "Skills",

                        width: 125,

                        suppressSorting: true,

                        cellRenderer: skillsCellRenderer,

                        filter: ""

                    },
                    {
                        headerName: "Proficiency",

                        field: "proficiency",

                        width: 120,

                        cellRenderer: percentCellRenderer,

                        filter: ""

                    },
                ]

            },
            {
                headerName: "Contact",

                children: [
                    { headerName: "Mobile", field: "mobile", width: 150, filter: "text" },
                    { headerName: "Land-line", field: "landline", width: 150, filter: "text" },
                    { headerName: "Address", field: "address", width: 500, filter: "text" }
                ]

            }
        ];

    }
```

Here is the html:

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid enable-sorting="true" enable-filter="true" row-height="22" row-selection="multiple" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel" [rowData]="rowData"
 (cell-clicked)="onCellClicked($event)" (column-resized)="onColumnEvent($event)"  class="ag-fresh" 
 >
   </ag-grid-ng2>
```

I inspect the page and here is it's screen shot

[image]

Here is the console error but this is not related to ag-grid

[image]

Now i don't know why grid is not showing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9707) might help point you in the right direction... seems that angular might be bogging something down by being in dev mode with 10000 rows trying to be rendered into the DOM of the ng-reflect-row-data. Be sure to get to what davidagee says in that thread

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did not know about ng-reflect but the problem was no about ng-reflect. Actually grid was rendering on the DOM but it's width was 0px by default. I just set it. And it is showing perfectly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some hours, i came to know the actual problem. Every thing was perfect. The actual problem was ag-grid width. It was 0px by  default. I just set it's width and it is working fine.

Comment: I had a similar issue but in my case the height was 0px by default, so make sure you set the height as well.

Comment: Also had similar issue. In my case the height and width used to be set to 100% (height: 100%). New to TS; apparently this does not work... BTW, that is even though Chrome dev console > Elements highlighted on the page the proper space the grid was supposed to take...

Comment: In my case, set height to 100% might also cause the form disappear. Try `100vh`

Comment: You can also set the option `domLayout` to `'autoHeight'` to automatically give the element the space it needs (without vertical scrolling within the container).

Comment: I was facing same issue, and found that column.minWidth was set to '375px' instead of 375 (number). Fixed after removing 'px' 
It was corrupting the width

Answer (score 7):

Grid is not showing or display due to `ag-grid.css` (ng-version="10.1.6") -

```
.ag-root-wrapper-body.ag-layout-normal {
    height: 0;
}
```

[image: before]

---

CSS modified in `styles.css`

```
.ag-root-wrapper-body.ag-layout-normal {
    height: auto;
}
```

[image: After]